# Still need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege with log_bin_trust_function_creators=1

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to backup my MySQL `databases` in `RackSpace` to `AWS`.

I have followed the advice from this [blog](https://techtavern.wordpress.com/2013/06/17/mysql-triggers-and-amazon-rds) and have set `log_bin_trust_function_creators=1` in my `AWS RDS` control panel and rebooted my db instance.

However after some time and some bits being moved I get the following error:

```
Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
  16GiB 0:36:39 [7.43MiB/s] [7.43MiB/s]
ERROR 1227 (42000) at line 21566: Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

I know there are a few triggers in my db and perhaps a couple of other goodies, notwithstanding my `grants` on the `aws` all seem sufficient:

```
mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, PROCESS, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, EVENT, TRIGGER ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD <secret> WITH GRANT OPTION |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What could be the problem? How do I solve it?

***EDIT***

Instead of dumping to `ssh` I just dumped it to `sed -n '21565,21567p'` so I assume that the output (line numbers) should be correct:

```
/*!50001 SET collation_connection      = utf8_general_ci */;
/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED */
/*!50013 DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
```

Comment: After you created that Parameter group did you attach that parameter group to your RDS?

Comment: Yes, I did: `Parameter Group my_group ( in-sync )`

Comment: Can you paste what is there at line 21566

Comment: Unfortunately I can't, as I was piping mysqldump via ssh tunnel... I'll dump it to a file, just to see for myself.

Comment: @error2007s Please see edited question.

Comment: Ok that definer line is causing issue /*!50013 DEFINER=`root`@`127.0.0.1` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */ remove that line and then try to run the back up

Comment: Thank you, you have saved the rest of my day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was the definer line in your DB. Always keep in mind:

You can specify a DEFINER value other than your own account only if you have the SUPER privilege.(Read below)

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-programs-security.html

And with RDS always keep in mind you don't get the Super Privilege.